# Linkedin api de autorização e rota do Angular 7

Tags: angular-7, authorization, api

Estou com um problema ao desenvolver uma tela de login utilizando Angular 7 e a API do Linkedin. O Backend está escrito em C#, e o problema é: 
O Linkedin requer uma URL de callback, e até onde consegui pesquisar isso não é negociável, diferente de Facebook ou Google, não é possível apenas recuperar os dados do usuário sem um redirect, por outro lado as URLs no Angular possuem o caractere `#` que não é aceito pelo Linkedin, e ao tentar registrar esse tipo de URL, temos o alerta:

> Redirect URLs cannot contain fragment identifiers (#)

Na tentativa de contornar a situação, passei a usar o `PathLocationStrategy`, que resolveu o problema mas trouxe outro, agora se o usuário atualizar a página, um erro `404`é lançado. Pesquisei algum tempo, mas não consegui uma solução.
Vocês sabem como consigo usar `PathLocationStrategy` e não ter um erro ao atualizar a página ou alguma outra forma de recuperar os dados do usuário usando o `HashLocationStrategy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver problema seguindo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833154/6580921) no SO, e para mim que sou iniciante em desenvolvimento front, coisa que faço bem raramente, era algo que eu realmente não entendia. Em caso de quebra do link, deixo reescrito a solução abaixo.
Segundo texto citado pelo autor da resposta:

> Quando você tem html5Mode habilitado, o caractere `#` não será usado em suas URLs. O simbolo `#` é útil porque não requer configuração do lado do servidor. Sem `#`a URL tem uma melhor aparência, porém isso também exige "rewrites" no lado do servidor

Como eu uso servidor IIS, fiz a seguinte alteração no meu web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```